# How to use Dojo in my Django application?

Tags: django, dojo

How do I use Dojo in my Django application? Please show me comprehensive examples on how to do this.
Any links to sample code for this combination will be appreciated

NB: I also don't mind examples using Dojango.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Give an example of what you would like to do? Page fragment update with Ajax? Flashy widgets? Emulate the marquee tag on Firefox?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the tutorials, screencasts, wiki, IRC, and blog available at the dojango homepage? http://code.google.com/p/dojango/

Answer (score 5):

You may have seen this blog post:
http://blog.uxebu.com/2008/07/26/ajax-with-dojango/

You can also try the various examples, blog articles and docs here.
http://code.google.com/p/dojango/

Answer (score 3):

1. copy [dojango](http://dojango.googlecode.com/files/dojango-0.5.2.tar.gz) over to you project root
2. include the following lin in your `settings.py` > `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`: `'dojango.middleware.DojoCollector',`
3. include the following lin in your `settings.py` > `TEMPLATE_DIRS`: `'/<project_location>/dojango/templates/dojango',` (so you can see some nice demos)
4. include the following lin in your `settings.py` > `INSTALLED_APPS`: `'dojango',`
5. change `from django.forms import *` to `from dojango.forms import *` in your `forms.py`